Irreducible components of the special (closed) fiber of a scheme proper flat over a discrete valuation ring.
Let $ f: Z \to T= \mathrm{Spec}A$ be a proper flat morphism from reduced scheme $Z$ to the spectrum of discrete valuation ring $A$. Let $ s\in T$ be the closed point. Then the irreduciblep components of $f^{-1}(s)$ are precisely $\{ f^{-1}(s) \cap Z_i : f^{-1}(s) \cap Z_i \neq \varnothing\}$, where $Z_1 , \dots, Z_n$ are the irreducible component of $Z$ ?

No, $Z$ could be irreducible.

@red_trumpet : O.K. Bad news. I am struggling with some proof and if this question was true then I could prove the theorem but since this is not true, I think that I should grope other method.

@red_trumpet : If you're interested, can I post a link to such a related question? ..

@red_trumpet : O.K.  I think I solved original problem. Thank you for comment.
